# Using objects inside list as function arguments in lapply

Tags: r, lapply

I am trying to learn different ways to use to the objects inside a list as the `FUN` arguments in `lapply`. Take this data:

```
A <- list(a = matrix(0, ncol = 3, nrow = 3), b = matrix(0, ncol = 3, nrow = 3))
B <- list(a = matrix(1, ncol = 1, nrow = 3), b = matrix(1, ncol = 1, nrow = 3))
D <- mapply(FUN="list", A, B, SIMPLIFY=F, USE.NAMES=F)
D <- lapply(D, `names<-`, c("first", "second"))
D
[[1]]
[[1]]$`first`
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0

[[1]]$second
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    1
[3,]    1


[[2]]
[[2]]$`first`
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0

[[2]]$second
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    1
[3,]    1
```

Desired result:

```
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0
[4,]    1    1    1

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0
[4,]    1    1    1
```

This is how I would normally do it:

```
lapply(D, function(x) rbind(x$first, as.numeric(x$second)))
```

Now I am wondering whether there is a way to avoid using `function(x)` and repeating all those *x*s. Something like:

```
lapply(D, "rbind", <args>)
```

How can I let `rbind` (or any other function) know that I am referring to objects within the frame of `lapply`?

Thank you,

K.

Comment: It's usually not possible if you nest several functions (e.g., `rbind`, `as.numeric` and `$`).

Comment: You can do something like `lapply(D, do.call, what = cbind)`. The same would work with `rbind` if you didn't have a one-column matrix but a one-row matrix or vector.

Comment: @Roland using the same idea,  `tcbind <- function(...) t(cbind(...));
lapply(D, do.call, what = tcbind)`

Comment: @agstudy Well, of course, there are practically no limitations if you define a function outside of `lapply`. But that is not much different from using an anonymous function within `lapply`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "avoid using `function(x)` and repeating all those `x`s", we could use `with()`:

```
lapply(D, with, rbind(first, as.numeric(second)))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

As per the commments changed the code to keep only the right solution.

---

As some of the commentators said, the problem is that `B` would need to be transposed, to find an elegant solution. You should have a look to `library(purrr)` because with that the whole problem reduces to:

```
map2(A, B, ~ rbind(.x, t(.y)))
# $`a`
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    0    0    0
# [2,]    0    0    0
# [3,]    0    0    0
# [4,]    1    1    1

# $b
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    0    0    0
# [2,]    0    0    0
# [3,]    0    0    0
# [4,]    1    1    1
```

What `map2` does is that it takes 2 lists and applies the function to each element of these lists. The `~` syntax is a shortcut for `function(.)`

Comment: In the same spirit, if we want to operate on `D` directly, we could: `transpose(D) %>% pmap(~ rbind(.x, t(.y)))`

Comment: Also, the two methods don't produce identical results when the matrix is not just `0`s. The upper matrix is transposed with the first method